# Selected list/menu to show def button

Tags: javascript

Question:

How can I do in JavaScript like this ya.. when I select open, button Open will appear.

```
if selected = 'open'
  out='Open Button'
else if selected ='edit'
  out='Edit Button'
 else 
  out='Closed button'
```

---

```
Button = <input type="submit" name="Open" id="button" value="submit">
selected =  <select name="select" id="select">
            <option value="Open">Open</option>
            <option value="Edit">Edit</option>
            </select>
```

Arhh really noob in that case.. sorry

Comment: you never responded to a comment for your other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831378/javascript-display-dif-button-when-dif-selected, which if you responded with an answer could of most certainly done what this question asks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you question asks see if this helps

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showOpenButton(n){

 if(n.value == "Open"){

 if(!document.getElementById("openBtn")){

   var oelm = document.getElementById('select');
   var btn = document.createElement("input");
   btn.type="submit";
   btn.value="Open Button";
   btn.id="openBtn"


   oelm.parentNode.appendChild(btn);
}
}

}
</script>


  <select name="select" id="select" onchange="showOpenButton(this)">
       <option value="">select one</option>
       <option value="Open">Open</option>
       <option value="Edit">Edit</option>
 </select>
```

// new function might help with your newly still hard to understand requirements

```
 function cBtn(n){

 var e = n.value;

 // if element placeholde exist remove it
 if(document.getElementById('div_btn_placeholder')){
   var tmp = document.getElementById('div_btn_placeholder'); // may need to set its css attribute display value to inline
  tmp.parentNode.removeChild(tmp);
  }

 var e = (n.selectedIndex==0) ? "Close" : n.value; //close or use other selected values on the button

 var d = document.createElement("div"); // easer to create a placeholde then can remove if defined
d.id="div_btn_placeholder";


var oelm = document.getElementById(n.id);
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.type="submit";
btn.value= e + " Button";
btn.id="btn" + e
btn.name=e;

oelm.parentNode.appendChild(d);

d.appendChild(btn)

}


function showOpenButton(n){

switch (n.value){
case "Open":cBtn(n); break;
case "Edit":cBtn(n); break;
default:cBtn(n);
}
}
```

Comment: ya it work, but only if i selected open.when i selected edit doesn't work and the submit button also still appeared..my question is' if i select value Open then button Open show and if i select value Edit than button Edit will show.btw thanks

Comment: sorry you never state that in your question ok, ill edit my answer

Comment: lol this one if selected = 'open'
  out='Open Button'
else if selected ='edit'
  out='Edit Button'
 else 
  out='Closed button'
hehe btw thanks

Comment: sorry boss,one more thing..how can i place the button.currently button will appear after selected right..but if i want the button showing somewhere else how ya..

Comment: look for the `var oelm` and add a id you wish to use for a place holder `var oelm = document.getElementById('mainButtonHolder');` and add element with the same corresponding `id` `<div id="mainButtonHolder"></div>` you'll then be able to place button any where you like

Comment: Mr David can i get your email.easy for me to send the code for you

Comment: @GreenCat i will go in to javascript CHAT and ask me a question in there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4438/discussion-between-david-and-greencat)